# How can I format the hardrive of laptop when I am getting error code 0x0000428

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

Here's the scenario.
I have a HP laptop in which I installed Windows 10 Technical Preview a few months ago.
Now, when I tried to turn it ON, it gave me an error "Your PC/device needs to be repaired", error 0x0000428.
What I exactly want to do is, I want to format my entire hard drive so that I can reinstall Windows 7 in it but I don't know how to format it as I am unable to do anything with that error code in my laptop.
I don't have disc for Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Comment: I can do that but how is it possible for me to format the harddrive when I am not able to load the windows at all? Neither in normal mode or in safe mode. @karel

Comment: one does not need windows to format a hard drive. do you have a win7 instalation cd , because formatting can be part of the process of installing, just step carefully through the first bits about selecting the location for the file system, and get into the "advanced" buttons during install.  You can format right there prior to installing the OS.

Comment: Download the GParted iso file and burn it to a CD or write it on a USB flash drive by following the instructions on [GParted Live on USB](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php). Set the boot priority in the BIOS/UEFI to boot first from the disk with GParted and then boot from the GParted CD/USB and format your hard drive. The default format for installing Windows on a drive or partition is NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Burn a linux live CD. Preferably ubuntu. (or a USB drive if your laptop supports boot from USB).
Mount the drive to get any data out of it. If required.
Run a partition manager like gparted.
select your hard drive and format it.
Now you can boot from the windows 7 installation disk/drive.

Also if you have a windows 7 installation disk, you can use it to format the disk as well.